# Common N-gon problem

Tags: modeling

I keep coming across the same problem when modeling where I add an edge loop to get some detail in a certain area but i only need to for that area.

Underneath is an example of what I mean:

[image]

What is the right/best thing to do in this situation?

would it be best to go with an edge loop all the way around the model?
or maybe make a triangle in the corner?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi. Seems like two slightly different questions combined: 1) "How do I only add details to one part of a model?" (or "limiting the effects of an edge loop") and 2) "What to do with an n-gon?" If that n-gon appears when inserting an edge loop then there is problem with the geometry. If you created it as a potential solution to limiting where the edge loop goes then is this question even about n-gons? May be a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: If you intend to use a subdivision surface modifier, all is ok as it'll do the job for you. If not you should complete your question about what you want to finally do with this mesh.

Comment: Subdivision surface modifier fixed it for me, thanks lemon!